# MATLAB Average Every 5 Elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

I want to take a large matrix and take the average of all 5x5 grids in it.

The matrix is 245x85x1255.I  reshaped the matrix into a 5x4165x1255 size (the z dimension is not that important) and I want to take the average of elements 1:5, 5:10, 10:15 etc in each row. And then, with the resulting matrix, I want to average the five columns. Then I'll resize it back to it's original shape (but smaller of course).

I don't have to do it this way. I just need to take a 5x5 grid and average all the points in it. Then I take the next 5x5 grid next to it and average all those points.

Here's how I did it for the first 5x5 grid:

```
A = data_SpecificArea(:,1:5,:);
B = mean(A,2);
C = mean(B,1);
```

** Here's the working code using blockproc

```
% Change dataAll_SpecificArea to a 1x1 degree grid (5x5 block averaging)
fun = @(block_struct) mean(block_struct.data);
A = blockproc(dataAll_SpecificArea,[5 1],fun); % Size goes from 245x85x1255 to 49x85x1255
B = blockproc(A,[1 5],fun); % Size is 49x17x1255
```

Comment: Is the overlap of adjacent blocks intentional? `1:5` is 5 element but `5:10` is 6 element and overlaps previous block. Maybe you are looking for `1:5`, `6:10`, `11:15`, ... In that case you should use `1:5:4161` instead of `1:4:4161`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) for that. For example,

```
fun = @(block_struct) mean(block_struct.data);
new_matrix = blockproc(old_matrix,[5 5],fun);
```