# taking moving average by matlab

Tags: matlab, average

I have some problem to analyze my data:
suppose there is a matrix

```
year month flow
72  1   34
72  1   43
72  1   55
72  1   34
72  1   43
72  1   55
72  1   34
72  1   43
72  1   55
72  1   34
72  1   43
72  1   55
72  1   34
72  1   43
72  1   55
72  1   34
72  1   43
72  1   55
72  2   34
72  2   43
72  2   55
```

now I want to take average of starting 10 values and than next ten values and so on. in this. basically I want to take the average of flow values for the 10 days of each month like from jan 1,1972 to jan 10, 72(row 10) and than jan 11,1972 to jan 20,1972 for that I tried

```
[unX,~,subs] = unique(D(:,1:2),'rows');
out          = [unX accumarray(subs,D(:,3),[],@nanmean)];
```

but as it gives the average of whole jan (1 value in column 2) I want to use it for only first ten days and then so on

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: related question: [How to calculate the standard deviation for every 100 points in a nx3 vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673073/how-to-calculate-the-standard-deviation-for-every-100-points-in-a-nx3-vector), just change 100 to 10 and use `mean` instead of `std`.

Comment: Keep your code but instead of working off column 2 (i.e. month) make a new column that just increments after every 10 values? something like `ceil(0:0.1:5)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB Average Every 5 Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496146/matlab-average-every-5-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `nanmean` by a custom function

```
 >> out = [unX accumarray(subs,D(:,3),[],@(x) nanmean( x(1:10)  ) )];
```